# Change html background to image from video if on mobile

Tags: html, css, image, video, mobile

I'm currently developing a website which uses an autoplay video background, however this scales badly on mobile and only sits in the top third of the screen...

Would it be possible in CSS to detect a mobile user, and change the background to a suitable portrait image?

You can view the webpage here: https://content.obstrude.com/login

As you can see, the video works nicely on PC, however on mobile fills the top third of the screen!

```css
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

img {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">

  <title>
    OBSTRUDE - LOGIN
  </title>
</head>

<body onload="document.body.style.opacity='1'">
  <video autoplay playsinline muted>
      <source src="/static/img/login.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep you could use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to detect a narrow screen width.

Something like this:

```
// this would affect screen widths up to 600px
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .className {
    /* put your mobile styles here */
  }
}
```

Check out this article on the matter https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-css-media-queries/

For your exact use case, I would recommend doing away with the video altogether and instead using css animations to achieve the same effect. You can then instead adjust them to also animate on mobile in the way that you want.

Comment: I will give this a go now, and let you know if this works! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cant get it to work, it doesn't make a difference because the non mobile styles are just overwriting the mobile ones specified in the above code snippet^^

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you've written your styles to fix this? As this should work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example using `media-queries`.

Resize the browser to see it work.

```css
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

img {
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  img {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  video {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
  <title>
    OBSTRUDE - LOGIN
  </title>
</head>

<body onload="document.body.style.opacity='1'">
  <video autoplay playsinline muted>
      <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=Could+also+use+this+as+poster.">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This sort of works, however it places the new image in the foreground and you cant see content behind it...

Comment: Then just set `video { opacity: 0;}` in the media query... See edits in my answer.

Comment: I set it to 0 and what happens now, is you cant click in any of the form content on the page or any other content, its as if the invisible image is still masking everything. So i set the zindex of both the image and video to 0

Answer (score 0):

You can also toggle`display` property from `none` to `block` and vise-versa to switch between video and image depending upon the size of the screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
      img {
        display: none;
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        video {
          display: none;
        }
        img {
          display: block;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <video autoplay muted>
        <source src="sample.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

img {
     display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
video {
      display: none;
      }
img {
     display: block;
     }
   }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">

  <title>
    OBSTRUDE - LOGIN
  </title>
</head>

<body onload="document.body.style.opacity='1'">
  <video autoplay playsinline muted>
      <source src="/static/img/login.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <img src="/static/img/image.png">
</body>

> You just need to make display hide and show when you want.For example at mobile view you can simply make display of video none and for image make it display block

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries for that:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .background {
    background-image: xyz.png;
  }
  
  video {
   display: none;
  }
}
```